# Statistical test to determine if Active Learning has provided a significant improvement?

Tags: statistical-significance, active-learning

I am conducting various active learning experiments on two Biomedical Relation Extraction corpora:

- 2018 n2c2 challenge: 41000 test samples
- DDI Extraction corpus: 5700 test samples

and  using four different machine learning methods: Random Forest, BiLSTM-based model, Clinical BERT, and Clinical BERT with an extended input.

Initially, I evaluated the performance of all 4 methods on both corpora using all the available data (passive learning setting). Then, I conducted additional experiments using 3 different active learning query strategies (random sampling, least confidence, and BatchBALD) on both corpora, using up to 50% of the data. All experiments were repeated 5 times with different random seeds.

The specific active learning process followed in the experiments is as follows:

Randomly select 2.5% of the total dataset to create the labeled dataset, while the remaining data forms the unlabeled pool.
In the active learning step, query 2.5% of the total data, retrain the model from scratch, and test the newly trained model on the test set, measuring precision, recall, and F1-score.
Stop the process when 50% of the entire dataset has been annotated, i.e. 19 iterations have been done.

**Is there a statistical test suitable for this experimental (C=2 corpora, M=4 methods, S=2 query strategies + random baseline, 5 repetitions of each experiment) setup that allows me to determine if one of the query strategies has performed signifantly better?**

Comment: I think important details are missing. The gist of active learning is that you select additional data points to label so that you improve the performance one particular model (unless you use random sampling). This can bias the selected data points in subtle ways, which has to be taken into account when evaluating performance. This paper might be of interest:  Active Surrogate Estimators: An Active Learning Approach to Label-Efficient Model Evaluation https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2202.06881

Comment: I added more details about the active learning setting.

Comment: What do you mean by "significant"? I you mean "statistically significant" then it would simply mean that you want to test if the before vs after difference is non-zero, but if your sample size is large enough, many statistical tests will detect tiny differences. Likely you are interested in "practical significance" i.e. being higher than some subjective threshold that *you* need to define.

Comment: At my work even tiny improvements are "practical" if they improve customer experience and/or revenue. That's often determined by the scale of the problem. So then the question is really how to measure whether there is a small improvement reliably. That's tricky if the evaluation/holdout dataset is small.

Comment: @Tim you can put both cases into your answer

Comment: @Tim Yes, I wanted to determine if the difference was statistically significant. You are totally right that I should define the threshold to determine what a significant improvement with respect to passive learning is. It would be still interesting to determine if one of the query strategies is significantly better than the others. I will modify my question.

Comment: @dipetkov I have added the sizes of the datasets. I am working in an experimental setting for research purposes, not in a comercial product

Comment: Sample size is not the only input into a statistical hypothesis test. It's also necessary to have knowledge of the variability (signal-to-noise ratio) and the effect size to detect (whether the effect is practically relevant or research purposes relevant).

Comment: I am aware of it.  My main problem is I  have C=2 corpora, M=4 methods S=3 query strategies and 5 repetitions of each experiments. Having this setup what would be the optimal statistical test to determine if one of the 3 query strategies is significantly better? 
I was thinking about the [Friedman Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test), but should I consider each combination of corpus-method (C x M = 12 combinations) as a "different dataset"? Is there a better common option?

Comment: Is a statistical test a meaningful thing to be doing in the first place? (Personally I think the answer is no, which is why you are struggling with defining what "significantly better" actually means.) The two datasets (2018 n2c2 challenge and DDI Extraction corpus) appear to be research benchmarks. This means that (a) there are SOTA results that you can compare with and (b) you can review how relation extraction methods are evaluated in the literature. Isn't this the standard way to evaluate experimental settings for research purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible approach in a very similar experimental setup from [Ein-Dor et al. (2020)](https://aclanthology.org/2020.emnlp-main.638/) to assess the attainment of significant improvements of the AL query strategies over the random baseline.

Specifically, for each query strategy and method, I calculate the p-value of the two-sided Wilcoxon signed-rank and perform a Bonferroni correction  to account for the multiple strategies examined. To compute the p-value for a given strategy *S* and method, we compare the micro F1-score values for all pairs ($S_{cik}$, $R_{dik}$), where $R$ represents the results from the random baseline, $d \in D$, and $D$ represents the two distinct corpora, $i = {1, ..., 19}$ is the step/iteration index, and $k = {1, ..., 5}$ is the experiment number.

A possible implementation in Python would be:

```py
from scipy.stats import wilcoxon
from statsmodels.stats.multitest import multipletests
  
ALPHA = 0.05
BASELINE_NAME = "random sampling"
METHODS = ["BiLSTM", "BERT", "CNN", "CRF"]
STRATEGIES = ["LC", "BatchBALD"]

def test_al_strategies():
    # create an array to store the p-values for each strategy and scenario
    p_values = np.zeros((len(STRATEGIES), len(METHODS)))

    for j, method in enumerate(METHODS):
        method_p_values = []

        for i, strategy_name in enumerate(STRATEGIES):
            strategy_data = load_method_data(method=method, strategy=strategy_name)
            baseline_data = load_method_data(method=method, strategy=BASELINE_NAME)

            assert len(strategy_data) == len(baseline_data)

            # calculate the Wilcoxon signed-rank test p-value for the pairs
            _, p_value = wilcoxon(x=strategy_data, y=baseline_data)

            # store the p-value for the current strategy and method
            method_p_values.append(p_value)

        # perform Bonferroni correction on the p-values for the current scenario
        rejected, corrected_p_values, _, _ = multipletests(
            method_p_values, alpha=ALPHA, method="bonferroni"
        )

        # store the corrected p-values in the array
        p_values[:, j] = corrected_p_values

    # print the corrected p-values and indicate whether the null hypothesis is rejected or not
    for j, method in enumerate(METHODS):
        for i, strategy_name in enumerate(STRATEGIES):
            is_rejected = p_values[i, j] <= ALPHA
            print(
                f"Strategy {strategy_name} vs. {BASELINE_NAME} with method {method}: "
                f"p-value = {p_values[i, j]:.10f}, "
                f"null hypothesis is {'rejected' if is_rejected else 'not rejected'}"
            )
            print()
```